# Set Material Design Lite radio button option with jquery

Tags: jquery, material-design-lite

I have the following radio buttons in MDL. I would like to know how to set one of the options with jquery. I've tried various ways found on SO or the web.... but no one is working.

```
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="sex-option-1">
    <input type="radio" id="sex-option-1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="sex-options" value="1">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">Male</span>
</label>

<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="sex-option-2">
   <input type="radio" id="sex-option-2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="sex-options" value="2">
   <span class="mdl-radio__label">Female</span>
</label>
```

MDL version is 1.1.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try `$('sex-option-2').trigger('click');`?

Comment: No I hadn't try. Just tried without success... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's how to check radio buttons in MDL:

```
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialRadio.check();
```

There is also an uncheck method:

```
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialRadio.uncheck();
```

And for further reference since the MDL javascript is poorly documented, here are the methods for all the other input types:

Checkbox:

```
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialCheckbox.check();
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialCheckbox.uncheck();
```

Switch:

```
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialSwitch.on();
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialSwitch.off();
```

Textfield:

```
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialTextfield.change('new text');
```

IconToggle:

```
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialIconToggle.check();
document.getElementById('sex-option-1').parentNode.MaterialIconToggle.uncheck();
```

Comment: you say it does not work, but then what would be the correct way to make it work as intended?

Comment: The methods I give in this answer work as intended. I meant that the previous answer submitted by Renaud T. doesn't work.

Comment: missing "t" in parentNode.MaterialTexfield

Answer (score 0):

By taking inspiration from https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4164 a solution is as follow:

```
$('#sex-option-1').parent().removeClass('is-checked');
```

to uncheck and

```
$('#sex-option-1').parent().addClass('is-checked');
```

to check