# MDL: set values / status of components in javascript programatically

Tags: javascript

I am an absolute beginner in java and html.
I am trying to load my html components from a json variable, at the beginning of the page load, and after receiving a websocket.
To be sure connection and html in loaded, I use this:

```
connection.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
console.log('Connected: ');
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    console.log('complete: ');
    getDataConfig();     
}
```

getDataConfig() fills the json, and must set radios, texts and sliders, but do no work.

So I tryed to do it by a simple button that calls a function DALE() (just for radios):

```
function dale() {
console.log("DALE");
document.getElementById('Datobarra0').checked = true;
document.getElementById('Datobarra1').checked = false;
document.getElementById('Datobarra2').checked = false;
```

}

this is html for radio buttons:

```
<div>
    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Dato Barra</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra0">
                        <input type="radio" id="Datobarra0" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="0" >
                        <span class="mdl-radio__label">NADA</span>
                    </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra2">
                        <input type="radio" id="Datobarra2" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="2" >
                        <span class="mdl-radio__label">RPM</span>
                    </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra1">
                        <input type="radio" id="Datobarra1" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="1" >
                        <span class="mdl-radio__label">VEL</span>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Nothing seems to work.
I tryied many, many ways for this.
I do not want to use jquery because is another new thing to learn, I know C and C++, so java seems to be easier for me.

Any help?
Thanks in advance
Gustavo.

```js
function dale() {
    console.log("DALE");
    document.getElementById('Datobarra0').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('Datobarra1').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('Datobarra2').checked = false;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/google-fonts.css">
    <script src="vendor/material.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/mainconfig.js"></script>

    <style>
        td {
            justify-content: left;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        tr {
            justify-content: left;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .mdl-radio__label {
            justify-content: left;
            text-align: left;
        }
        
        .mdl-button {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>



<body>
<div>
        <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Dato Barra</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra0">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra0" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="0" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">NADA</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra2">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra2" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="2" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">RPM</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra1">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra1" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="1" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">VEL</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" onclick="dale()">UPDATE</button>
    </body>
```

UPGRADE:
Well, I tryed to minimize code and it´s still not working:
If I remove ""  it works, but there is no more a MDL web...
NOT WORKING CODE:

```js
function dale() {
    document.getElementById('Datobarra0').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('Datobarra1').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('Datobarra2').checked = false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Dato Barra</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra0">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra0" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="0" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">NADA</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra2">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra2" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="2" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">RPM</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra1">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra1" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="1" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">VEL</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Raised button -->

    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" onclick="dale()">UPDATE</button>


</body>



</html>
```

WORKING CODE:

```js
function dale() {
    document.getElementById('Datobarra0').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('Datobarra1').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('Datobarra2').checked = false;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">


</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Dato Barra</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra0">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra0" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="0" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">NADA</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra2">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra2" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="2" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">RPM</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra1">
                            <input type="radio" id="Datobarra1" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="1" >
                            <span class="mdl-radio__label">VEL</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Raised button -->

    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" onclick="dale()">UPDATE</button>


</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Is the problem that your functions are not being called, or is the problem that they are not doing what you expect?

Comment: Hi!,functions are called, but state of radio button do not change, thats the problem.

Comment: As written, this should work. Can you update the question to include a sample snippet with the button wired up and not working?

Comment: Done (hope it´s ok, a new thing to learn!)

Comment: It looks like everything works to me in your example.  I think where you're getting hung up is that the css is hiding your actual radio button.  If you change your styling to reflect the state of the `input`, I think you will see the results you want. You can read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221259/custom-radio-button-using-css

Comment: Ah, it looks like you'll need to use the built in objects to access the properties appropriately. This question should clear it up for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783797/set-material-design-lite-radio-button-option-with-jquery

Comment: HI ChrisG,  it works, at least with radios. As the thread says, there is no documentation about it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade:
As ChrisG comments above, there is a thread about this.
This works:

```js
function Dale() {
 document.getElementById('Datobarra0').parentNode.MaterialRadio.check();
    document.getElementById('Datobarra1').parentNode.MaterialRadio.uncheck();
    document.getElementById('Datobarra2').parentNode.MaterialRadio.uncheck();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/mainconfig.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        td {
            justify-content: left;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        tr {
            justify-content: left;
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .mdl-radio__label {
            justify-content: left;
            text-align: left;
        }
        
        .mdl-button {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
        <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Dato Barra</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra0">
                        <input type="radio" id="Datobarra0" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="0" >
                        <span class="mdl-radio__label">NADA</span>
                    </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="Datobarra1">
                        <input type="radio" id="Datobarra1" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="1">
                        <span class="mdl-radio__label">VEL</span>
                    </label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio" for="Datobarra2">
                        <input type="radio" id="Datobarra2" name="Datobarra" class="mdl-radio__button" value="2" >
                        <span class="mdl-radio__label">RPM</span>
                    </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" onclick="Dale()">DALE</button>
    
    </body>



</html>
```

Comment: You mentioned other components as well. You can dig through the source to see how you would interact with those as well. [Slider](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/slider/slider.js#L167), [TextField](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/textfield/textfield.js#L218), etc